# Amazon EC2 suddenly remove access control headers from my packets?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, django

I have a django server on EC2 instance that serve lots of customers via REST API.
I put a middleware in django to allow access control from anywhere by automatically adding access control headers on all responses.

The middleware is well tested, used by hundreds of servers, and worked perfectly for the past couple of months. I trust it works 100%.

Yesterday, suddenly all our clients got 502 return code on all our APIs. Looking at the error in chrome we see `"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'xxx' is therefore not allowed access."`

This is the kind of message I'd expect to see if it wasn't for the middleware. But I know it works. After few hours the problem stopped on its own, without me doing anything.

So my question is - how could this have happened? Why would amazon EC2 suddenly temper with my outgoing traffic? And most importantly - how can I prevent it in the future? I didn't see anything in the logs to explain this (not in django and not in nginx), and since it happened on its own and stopped on its own I suspect its amazon-related. Maybe something to do with their internal routing or load balancing?

Thanks,

Comment: *Why would amazon EC2 suddenly temper with my outgoing traffic?*  They wouldn't.  Do you have an Elastic or Application Load Balancer (ELB/ALB) in your stack?  (If not, then *"their internal routing or load balancing"* does not have any components capable of manipulating your traffic.)

Comment: And what about error messages? is it possible that amazon would generate their own error messages for different problems before reaching my server, and those messages won't have cors header? for the client it might look the same as if I didn't include those headers in my api. Thanks.